# How to find data from a GET array with parameters already present

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, api

Sorry, the title isn't worded very well. I'm using a category choose to choose a category from an API. I currently get the list of categories, filter through their names, and display them in the category chooser. When the user clicks submit, I want the to parse through the API and find the id associated with that category name. Here's an example output from the API:

```
{
"_id": "5c2fde414502d923ceafaa30",
"title": "Category 2",
"description": "My second category, testing 123",
"createdAt": "2019-01-04T22:29:21.047Z",
"updatedAt": "2019-01-04T22:29:21.047Z",
"__v": 0
},
```

Here's the code I use for the Category Chooser:

*JS*:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:2672/categories", function (json) {
$('#category-chooser').empty();
$('#category-chooser').append($('<option>').text("Choose a Category"));
$.each(json, function (i, obj) {
$('#category-chooser').append($('<option>').text(obj.title));
});
});
```

*HTML*

```
<select id="category-chooser" class="form-control" name="category">
<option selected="selected">blank</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the json returned from getJSON somewhere outside the callback, your submit button would fire off something like below:

```
function getCategoryId(){
    const categoryChooser = document.getElementById('category-chooser');
    const categorySelected = categoryChooser.value;
    json.forEach(entry => {
        if(entry.title === categorySelected){
            return entry["_id"];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, that looks good! I'll test that out and let you know if it works. Sorry if the question was poorly worded

Comment: Sounds good, just so you know I did make one adjustment for a typo just now.

Comment: When running this code, It doesn't appear to be running the .forEach code, I can't get a console.log command to show up at all....